# How to get Test Step number and print it in script logs

Tags: soapui

I am using SOAPUI 5.3. I have a test suite with 80 test steps.
After testrunner runs the suite i want to print the following on to the logs.
Test step number
Test step name and
Test Step status.

I was able to figure out how to print test step name and status but not test step number. I tried to get test step index but i could not get it to work. I am running this at test suite level

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def testSuite = context.testCase.testSuite;                        //get current test suite
def totalTestSteps = context.getTestCase().getTestSteps().size()   //get int total test steps for the given test case
def currentTestStep = context.getCurrentStep().name                //get name of current step
for(n in (0..totalTestSteps-1))
{    
    def testStepName = context.getTestCase().getTestStepAt(n).name
    def testStepNumber = n
    if (testStepName == currentTestStep){
        log.info(testStepName + " is at position " + testStepNumber)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: or you can do def testStepNumber = n + 1. If you want it to be human readable. e.g starts with 1 instead of 0. Let me know if that is what you needed.

Comment: Glad I was able to help! Please, select as final answer if you think that this is what you needed. Best Regards, Gregory.